# AS3 RegEx: Match Keywords

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am trying to match ANY of the few keywords in a string using RegEx in AS3. Following is an example.

```
var sourceString = "No, I am working on it. There might be some delay.";
var keywords = ["no", "delay"];
```

I need to check if any of the keywords are present in the source string. The keywords and source strings will be dynamic. I need to take the source string as an input from the user and then search some keywords in that string. Can there be one generic RegEx pattern to achieve this?

Comment: I can do a simple loop and use indexOf to find out. However, this approach is slow and I am looking for RegEx solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a new [`RegExp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) object and use that to match against the source string.

For example:

```
var sourceString = "No, I am working on it. There might be some delay.";
var keywords = ["no", "delay"];

var expression:RegExp = new RegExp(keywords.join("|"), "ig");

if (expression.test(sourceString)) {
    // Match found
} else {
    // No match found
}
```

(Untested code.)